# SQL Pivot . need output in below format

Tags: sql

Below is the table temp_v1 has the details .

```
HOURS      NAME     SALARY DATE 
3          JOHN     60     14-Jul-16    
5          JOHNSON  10     14-Jul-16    
34         JOHNSON  70     16-Jul-16    
45         JOHNSON  90     18-Jul-16
```

I want the output as -------------->

```
DATE        JOHN_Hrs John_sal JOHNSON_Hrs JOHNSON_sal
14-Jul-16   3        60       5           10
16-Jul-16   0        0        34          70
18-Jul-16   0        0        45          90
```

Can someone help me in doing this pls .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way to `pivot` your results using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select salary_date,
       max(case when name = 'john' then hours else 0 end) john_hours,
       max(case when name = 'john' then salary else 0 end) john_sal,
       max(case when name = 'johnson' then hours else 0 end) johnson_hours,
       max(case when name = 'johnson' then salary else 0 end) johnson_sal
from yourtable
group by salary_date
```